# CSS: how link width of elements without using tables

Tags: jquery, css

Have a tree menu made using nested ULs 3 levels deep.  The bottoms 2 levels are hidden/collapsed by default.  The bottom 3rd level shows a comparison of a "left" versus "right" value.  I want to make all of the "left" spans the same width, but not a fixed width.  I thought about a jquery loop to find the max width of all such spans, then go back and set them all to that max width.  But when hidden, jquery width() is always 0.  So I would have to expand the whole list first, do this work, then collapse it again.  Even then, setting the width via jquery didn't seem to do anything.  The spans have a style="width: 93px;" in them, but the actual width didn't change.  Is there any CSS2/3 way of linking the width of these elements?  Or a better javascript way?

```
<ul class="hidden">
  <li>
    <span class="left">cat</span>
    &hArr;
    <span class="right">dog</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="left">bird</span>
    &hArr;
    <span class="right">horse</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="left">some long text</span>
    &hArr;
    <span class="right">more long text</span>
  </li>
</ul>

span.left{text-align:right;}
ul.hidden{display:none;}
```

Comment: Your instinct to use JavaScript is correct. I assume the "display" is set to none? Setting it to block, and setting 'visibility: "hidden"' will fix your jQuery issue -- at least it has in the browsers I've tested on. The other option is to use YUI3 Library. You will not be able to use CSS to make equal widths unless setting the actual width.

(use Antony Mills answer. Simple and easy to implement.)

Comment: Why not use a table? It seems perfectly suitable here! If the data is best fit in a table, than it should be a table! Tables for layouts are evil, tables in general are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS properties for displaying as table cells (e.g. http://ajaxian.com/archives/display-table) but really, you're describing what is semantically a table. Why not just use table markup? It's not cursed or anything.

Comment: Because this I need a hierarchical tree menu with expand collapse.  I don't know how to create that hierarchy using tables except to put tables inide tables inside tables.  But at the bottom level, the elements would be aligned only within that sub-sub-table.  Not at with any other sub-sub-table.  Does that make sense?

Comment: In that case, what you would have would be something like this. Make a table. Top-level: everything in the row is `colspan`ned. Second level: empty left cell, everything else in the row is `colspan`ned. Third level: use the third and fourth cells in the row to form your comparison cells. Then set it to toggle `display: none` on rows that shouldn't be shown when you collapse them.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that will work.  Just will make the jquery for selecting the correct rows to expand/collapse a bit tricky.  Probably use classes on the rows to represent the depth, and use jquery .nextUntil to get all following rows until row of same class (depth).

Comment: Yes, that should work. A little bit of extra complexity in the toggle code is definitely worth letting the browser do the heavy lifting on the layout side. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend changing the left spans to a div and setting the width of the "left" class to: 
`min-width:100px;` for example, then if it needs more room, it will dynamically expand beyond 100px. The reason for the change of tags is because span tags are usually useful for when you want to add text styling, but not for when you want to apply widths, heights, margins, padding, etc... thats jusy my opinion based on my experience though.

---

***Edit***

**Possible solution:** Set a border to your hidden ul and use the min-width property on it, and the width of the whole list will change based on the largest list item.

Comment: This doesn't align it if there is an element with a width greater than 100px though.

Comment: But I need them to all expand together.  As if they were a column in a table.

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that you were using a table, I didn't take a close enough look at your code. I recommend using a table for doing what youre trying to do, because it is the easiest way to meet your goal, then my method will work and the width of the column will be as big as the biggest cell contained in it.